# Installing ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso on Dell R730 server

Tags: dell

When trying to install the `ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso` image via a USB stick I get following error:

> (initramfs) Unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Before error message is show two other messages is shown:

> i8042: No controller found
>
> ACPI PCC probe failed

What is the problem and how do I get Ubuntu installed on the server?

Comment: how did you created the usb image? `ACPI PCC probe failed` you can ignore this or set `acpi=off` in the boot options.